# What model to fit given ACF and PACF (seasonal data)

Tags: time-series, seasonality, multiple-seasonalities, acf-pacf

I have highly seasonal data, (it's energy consumption) with mostly 24 hour and 168 hour (=1 week) periods and I have applied differencing by 168 hours (`diff(time_series,lag=168)`) to obtain something more stationary

[image: Plot of differenced]

because I don't see how I can fit any model on a series which has this many seasonalities (there is also a less obvious 12 hour period). 
Now I have plotted the acf and pacf and I was wondering about how to interpret these:

[image: ACF]

[image: PACF]

Lag=0 is not included because I used forecast::Acf. So on the pacf the obvious outliers are for lag=1,3 and 168.

I don't know if we can say that there is geometric or exponential decay in any of the correlograms, so any comments are welcome.

Comment: how many observations do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

[Selecting ARIMA p,d,q paramerters for hourly data with 24 hour cycle](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378347/selecting-arima-p-d-q-paramerters-for-hourly-data-with-24-hour-cycle/378348#378348) lays out a strategy for building 24 daily models and then using daily predictions from each of these models to predict hourly values. Pay particularly close attention to this reference [Forecasting data with multiple seasonality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399570/forecasting-data-with-multiple-seasonality/399590#399590) and https://autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/forecasting-at-an-hourly-level.

In summary there is more to forecasting than simply weighting the past (SARIMA) when latent factors ( holidays, level shifts , local time trends ) along with possible predictor series like temperature are critically important to detect and incorporate. Methods that extract latent deterministic structure are in effect pseudo-causal.

Relying on the past of the output series alone is equivalent to "drivers that navigate using only the rear-window " rather than both the rear-window and the front window.

Answer (score 0):

ARIMA, ACF and PACF are not useful for data with [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities). I strongly recommend you look at models that were designed for this use case, like [bats](/questions/tagged/bats) and [tbats](/questions/tagged/tbats).

Don't try to specify these models by hand (as you could specify ARIMA orders by looking at the ACF/PACF plots in the obsolete Box-Jenkins method). Instead, use a good implementation like the one in the `forecast` package for R.

Comment: In IrishStat's answer he talks about ARIMA, so you think this is not a good approach?

Comment: You can incorporate additional predictors into an ARIMA model, yielding an ARIMAX model, or run a regression with ARIMA errors ([there is a difference](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)). Yes, you can in principle model data with multiple seasonalities in this way. It just gets rather complicated, especially interpreting ACF/PACF plots, and if you just put in tons of dummies, you will get an overparameterized model. Better to use splines or harmonics. By which time you already almost have a TBATS model, so better to use that straight away.

Comment: Also: ARIMA deals with seasonality by (possibly repeated) seasonal differencing. In each difference, you essentially throw away one seasonal cycle's worth of data.

Comment: Here is a metaphor: yes, you can use a hammer to drive a screw into a wall. It's *possible*. But a hammer is made for nails, and there are better tools to address screw challenges. Like a screwdriver. In the exact same way, there are better models to address [tag:multiple-seasonalities] than trying to make ARIMA work. I recommend [the original TBATS publication by De Livera, Hyndman & Snyder (2011)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jasa.2011.tm09771).

Comment: Box-Jenkins modelling is not obsolete ...it just has been updated to deal with "data complications" . Identifying a minimally sufficient set of seasonal dummies is not necessarily an overparameterization just a possible "better paramaterization"